# Allow Face ID permission alert

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, iphone-x, face-id

My app (running in iPhone X Simulator Xcode 9.0.1) is asking me for permission to use Face ID.

The alert says:

`Do you want to allow <appName> to use Face ID?
This app was designed to use Touch ID and may not fully support Face ID.`

I was expecting that the few changes I made to the new APIs in the `LocalAuthentication` framework (e.g. `biometryType`) was supposed to basically work for Face ID.

Is there something else I need to do to make it so my app *is* designed to fully support Face ID?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears that you need to add the `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist` in order to support Face ID.

Also, the simulator alert is only for simulator, without that Info.plist key, the app apparently should crash on a real device without it.

Thanks to these dudes for helping me learn this -
[What is NSFaceIDUsageDescription - Face ID Usage Description Info.plist key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309440/what-is-nsfaceidusagedescription-face-id-usage-description-info-plist-key)

---

Protip:

Prior to the permission prompt, `[LAContext canEvaluatePolicy:error:]` returns `YES` for biometrics if the device is capable of it.

iOS won't prompt the user for permission until the first call to `[LAContext evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:]`.

If the user does **not** grant permission, then all future calls to `canEvaluatePolicy` will return `NO` (error Code=-6 "User has denied the use of biometry for this app."). This is an odd nuance.

Comment: regarding the error -6 "User has denied the use of biometry for this app" you may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470580/3172445

Comment: The app doesn't crash without `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` Test case:  physical iPhone X debbger via Xcode 9.2 and iOS 11.2 SDK. Results: I see the message: "This app was designed to use Touch ID and may not fully support Face ID." and the app does not crash.

Comment: @ChrisWoolfe edit - my mistake - perhaps they addressed the behavior in iOS 11.2? I would suggest you try 11.1 or 11.0 to ensure it won't crash

Comment: Is there a way to check if the permission prompt was shown?